# Python: Create a list with functions as members with arguments tuples from a provided list

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, list-comprehension

I have the following issue. A list of tuples with integers:

```
Dates_Tpls =  [(2015, 10, 1), (2015, 11, 1), (2015, 12, 1), (2016, 1, 1), (2016, 2, 1), (2016, 3, 1), (2016, 4, 1), (2016, 5, 1)]
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
Dates_Tpls_Test = [date(2015, 10, 1), date(2015, 11, 1), daye(2015, 12, 1), date(2016, 1, 1), date(2016, 2, 1), date(2016, 3, 1), date(2016, 4, 1), date(2016, 5, 1)]
```

The purpose is `Dates_Tpls_Test` to be used in a graph package (bokeh), where input is such a list for time axis.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension is your friend here:

```
Dates_Tpls_Test = [date(*x) for x in Dates_Tpls]
```

(the `*x` lets you use a tuple as a list of arguments to a function.)

Comment: Scott, this gives me an error: 'date' is not defined. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I assumed you had `date` properly imported since you used it in your code; apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: Scott, thank you. Based on your suggestion works better but not as desired. Instead of a list containg date(x,y,z) elements creates a list with datetime.date(x,y,z) elements

Comment: Then use whatever `date` you meant; I mistakenly assumed you meant the one in `datetime`.